# WebSense SSL man in the middle

Tags: networking, proxy, ssl

We have a websense proxy on the corporate network which does SSL man in the middle. This doesn't cause any problems when browsing but, when using the command line in Linux or OS X I continually get certificate verification errors. Obviously with the likes of curl or wget I can turn the verification off, however when using other tools (packer connecting to AWS for instance) I do not have that option.

We can't be the only people with this type of setup so was wondering if anyone knew how I could resolve this this problem.

Comment: You can have the host whitelisted in websense...  otherwise I don't think you have any option.